# PHP Pear Number_Words

Tags: php, oop, pear

)
I start to use PEAR Number_Word class, and it works greate! It convert numbers to a string by this way:

```
<?php
include_once 'Numbers/Words.php';
$number = 100254;
     $nw = new Numbers_Words();
     $numw = $nw->toWords($number);

     print $numw;

?>
```

But now I need to convert the same number to a different languages at the same time.
For exemple: I have number 100 and I need to convert it in the same time to English and French. I was trying to pass in the argument an array of two languages, but it's not work:

```
/**
     * Default Locale name
     * @var string
     * @access public
     */
    public $locale = 'en_US'; //__her I was try to pass an array, but no result__

    /**
     * Default decimal mark
     * @var string
     * @access public
     */
    public $decimalPoint = '.';

    // }}}
    // {{{ toWords()

    /**
     * Converts a number to its word representation
     *
     * @param integer $num     An integer between -infinity and infinity inclusive :)
     *                         that should be converted to a words representation
     * @param string  $locale  Language name abbreviation. Optional. Defaults to
     *                         current loaded driver or en_US if any.
     * @param array   $options Specific driver options
     *
     * @access public
     * @author Piotr Klaban <makler@man.torun.pl>
     * @since  PHP 4.2.3
     * @return string  The corresponding word representation
     */
    function toWords($num, $locale = '', $options = array())
    {
        if (empty($locale) && isset($this) && $this instanceof Numbers_Words) {
            $locale = $this->locale;
        }

        if (empty($locale)) {
            $locale = 'en_US';
        }

        $classname = self::loadLocale($locale, '_toWords');


        $obj = new $classname;


        if (!is_int($num)) {
            $num = $obj->normalizeNumber($num);

            // cast (sanitize) to int without losing precision
            $num = preg_replace('/(.*?)('.preg_quote($obj->decimalPoint).'.*?)?$/', '$1', $num);
        }

        if (empty($options)) {
            return trim($obj->_toWords($num));
        }
        return trim($obj->_toWords($num, $options));
    }
```

Please, halp me if you know how! Thank you in advance!

Comment: OOO, I solve this using tow different Object.include_once 'Numbers/Words.php';
$number = 100254;
     $nw = new Numbers_Words();
     $rus = $nw->toWords($number);
     $numw = $nw->toWords($number,$locale='ru');
 
     print $numw;
     print $rus;

Answer (score 0):

`Numbers_Words` does not support multiple languages at once.

You need to create a new `Numbers_Words` instance for every language.